# MVC3: underscores and spaces are stripped from url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, url, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a problem with a MVC 3 Application...
If I have a link like this:

```
http://localhost:15838/ByBU/OpenTask/Details/Excess_Casualty/Index_Clear
```

and the route for this url is:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "OpenTaskDetails",
            "{controller}/OpenTask/{action}/{BU}/{SLAName}",
            new { controller = "ByBU", action= "Details", BU = "BU", SLAName = "SLAName" },
            new [] { "SLA.Controllers" }
            );
```

When I set a breakpoint at the first line of "Details" action the variables `BU` and `SLAName` are: Excess (instead of `Excess_Casualty`), and `Index` (instead of `Index_Clear`).

It worked fine before, and then all of a sudden stopped working and I have no clue why it does that. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you make any changes that might account for this?

Comment: I personally don't think so. I was working on a separate controller, and then when i was doing some QA this happened.

Comment: @BeenishKhan The whole thing or just a specific section?

Comment: 1) Your comlpete web.config, just want to see all the settings. 2) Your Globa.ascx function having the routing info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Underscores are never recommended for URLs, so you may want to switch to dashes :

http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/dashes-vs-underscores/

"Google sees the dash as a word separator, while the underscore is perceived to be part of the word."

Comment: This fixed the issue. I changed the underscore to a dash and works fine.